# kafka topic creation faling when 3 brokers are up out of 4 in a cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

Kafka topic creation is failing in below scenarios:

Node is kafka cluster: 4

Replication factor: 4

Number of nodes up and running in cluster: 3

Below is the error:

```
./kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper :2181 --create --topic test_1 --partitions 1 --replication-factor 4
WARNING: Due to limitations in metric names, topics with a period ('.') or underscore ('_') could collide. To avoid issues it is best to use either, but not both.
Error while executing topic command : Replication factor: 4 larger than available brokers: 3.
[2018-10-31 11:58:13,084] ERROR org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidReplicationFactorException: Replication factor: 4 larger than available brokers: 3.
```

Is it a valid behavior or some known issue in kafka?

If all the nodes in a cluster should be up and running always then what about failure tolerance?

upating json file for increasing the replication factor for already created topic:

```
$cat /tmp/increase-replication-factor.json
{"version":1,
  "partitions":[
     {"topic":"vHost_v81drv4","partition":0,"replicas":[4,1,2,3]},
     {"topic":"vHost_v81drv4","partition":1,"replicas":[4,1,2,3]},
     {"topic":"vHost_v81drv4","partition":2,"replicas":[4,1,2,3]},
     {"topic":"vHost_v81drv4","partition":3,"replicas":[4,1,2,3]}
     {"topic":"vHost_v81drv4","partition":4,"replicas":[4,1,2,3]},
     {"topic":"vHost_v81drv4","partition":5,"replicas":[4,1,2,3]},
     {"topic":"vHost_v81drv4","partition":6,"replicas":[4,1,2,3]},
     {"topic":"vHost_v81drv4","partition":7,"replicas":[4,1,2,3]}
]}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a new topic is created in Kafka, it is replicated `N=replication-factor` times across your brokers. Since you have 3 brokers up and running and `replication-factor` set to `4` the topic cannot be replicated 4 times and thus you get an error.

When creating a new topic you either need to ensure that all of your 4 brokers are up and running or set the replication factor to a smaller value in order to avoid failure on topic creation when one of your brokers is down.

In case you want to create topic with replication factor set to `4` while one broker is down, you can initially create the topic with `replication-factor=3` and once your 4th broker is up and running you can modify the configuration of that topic and increase its replication factor by following the steps below (assuming you have a topic `example` with 4 partitions):

Create a `increase-replication-factor.json` file with this content:

```
{"version":1,
  "partitions":[
     {"topic":"example","partition":0,"replicas":[0,1,2,3]},
     {"topic":"example","partition":1,"replicas":[0,1,2,3]},
     {"topic":"example","partition":2,"replicas":[0,1,2,3]},
     {"topic":"example","partition":3,"replicas":[0,1,2,3]}
]}
```

Then execute the following command:

```
kafka-reassign-partitions --zookeeper localhost:2181 --reassignment-json-file increase-replication-factor.json --execute
```

And finally you'd be able to confirm that your topic is replicated across the 4 brokers:

```
kafka-topics --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic signals --describe
Topic:signals   PartitionCount:4    ReplicationFactor:4 Configs:retention.ms=1000000000
Topic: signals  Partition: 0    Leader: 2   Replicas: 0,1,2,3 Isr: 2,0,1,3
Topic: signals  Partition: 1    Leader: 2   Replicas: 0,1,2,3 Isr: 2,0,1,3
Topic: signals  Partition: 2    Leader: 2   Replicas: 0,1,2,3 Isr: 2,0,1,3
Topic: signals  Partition: 3    Leader: 2   Replicas: 0,1,2,3 Isr: 2,0,1,3
```

Regarding high availability let me explain how Kafka works:

Every *topic*, is a particular stream of data (similar to a table in a database). Topics, are split into *partitions* (as many as you like) where each message within a partition gets an incremental id, known as offset as shown below.

**Partition 0:**

```
+---+---+---+-----+
| 0 | 1 | 2 | ... |
+---+---+---+-----+
```

**Partition 1:**

```
+---+---+---+---+----+
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | .. |
+---+---+---+---+----+
```

Now a Kafka cluster is composed of multiple *brokers*. Each broker is identified with an ID and can contain certain topic partitions.

Example of 2 topics (each having 3 and 2 partitions respectively):

**Broker 1:**

```
+-------------------+
|      Topic 1      |
|    Partition 0    |
|                   |
|                   |
|     Topic 2       |
|   Partition 1     |
+-------------------+
```

**Broker 2:**

```
+-------------------+
|      Topic 1      |
|    Partition 2    |
|                   |
|                   |
|     Topic 2       |
|   Partition 0     |
+-------------------+
```

**Broker 3:**

```
+-------------------+
|      Topic 1      |
|    Partition 1    |
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
+-------------------+
```

Note that data is distributed (and *Broker 3* doesn't hold any data of *topic 2*).

Topics, should have a `replication-factor` > 1 (usually 2 or 3) so that when a broker is down, another one can serve the data of a topic. For instance, assume that we have a topic with 2 partitions with a `replication-factor` set to 2 as shown below:

**Broker 1:**

```
+-------------------+
|      Topic 1      |
|    Partition 0    |
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
+-------------------+
```

**Broker 2:**

```
+-------------------+
|      Topic 1      |
|    Partition 0    |
|                   |
|                   |
|     Topic 1       |
|   Partition 1     |
+-------------------+
```

**Broker 3:**

```
+-------------------+
|      Topic 1      |
|    Partition 1    |
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
+-------------------+
```

Now assume that *Broker 2* has failed. *Broker 1* and 3 can still serve the data for topic 1. So a `replication-factor` of 3 is always a good idea since it allows for one broker to be taken down for maintenance purposes and also for another one to be taken down unexpectedly. ***Therefore, Apache-Kafka offers strong durability and fault tolerance guarantees.***

**Note about Leaders:**
At any time, only one broker can be a leader of a partition and only that leader can receive and serve data for that partition. The remaining brokers will just synchronize the data (in-sync replicas). Also note that when the `replication-factor` is set to 1, the *leader* cannot be moved elsewhere when a broker fails. In general, when all replicas of a partition fail or go offline, the `leader` will automatically be set to `-1`.

Comment: I want my data to be replicated to 4 nodes so I want replication factor as 4 . But for testing fault tolerance of kafka service I am stopping kafka on one node. and during this time I am trying to create new topic. But as you mentioned all nodes should be up and running . So now in this case If I create topic with replication 3 then later Can I change replication to 4 for this newly created topic?

Comment: Seeing error while trying to increase replication factor "Partitions reassignment failed due to Partition reassignment data file is empty
kafka.common.AdminCommandFailedException: Partition reassignment data file is empty". My Json file is updated in question

Comment: @dcds There is a typo. You’ve missed a comma

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous: In  the above example you have mentioned " topic with 2 partitions with a replication-factor set to 2" but in the diagram you have created 3 partation with "0" id. Please let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: @ARPANCHAKARVARTY You're right. I've edited my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a valid behavior. When creating a new topic all nodes should be up and running.

[Confluence Replica placements - Initial placement](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+Replication#KafkaReplication-Replicaplacements)

> Only create the topic, make decision-based on current live brokers (manual create topic command);

All nodes **must not** be up and running while using this topic (after it is created)

[Apache documentation about replication factor](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/kafka/site/082/ops.html)

> The replication factor controls how many servers will replicate each message that is written. If you have a replication factor of 3 then up to 2 servers can fail before you will lose access to your data. We recommend you use a replication factor of 2 or 3 so that you can transparently bounce machines without interrupting data consumption.